# If I use Selenium WebDriver in java, do I need the source code of the application to test?

Tags: automated-tests

Can I run test using Selenium 2 without the source code of the application to test?. I want to use Selenium with Java (Eclipse).

Comment: More details would be good - are you testing a Java web app?

Comment: Yes I want to test a java web app, but I already did some test I don't need the source code of the app. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you do not need the source code, you can grab the element through the view source function. But more details would be good also.